# Batch - system can not find the file specified

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have the following batch file:

```
set file_name=workflow.xml

echo ^<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?^>> "%file_name%"
echo ^<?Siebel-Property-Set EscapeNames="true"?^>>> "%file_name%"
echo ^<ListOfPropertySetEx^>>> "%file_name%"

for /f "usebackq delims=|" %%f in (`dir /B /ON "%~1\SI0002\Workflow Process*"`) do 
(C:\cygwin\bin\grep -m1 -e "   PROCESS_NAME=\".*^\"" "%~1\SI0002\%%f" |  
C:\cygwin\bin\sed  "s/.*   PROCESS_NAME=\x22\(.*\)\x22/ <PropertySet 
FlowSearchSpec=\"\[Process Name\]=\^&apos;\1\^&apos;\"\/>/">> "%file_name%")

echo ^</ListOfPropertySetEx^>>> "%file_name%"
```

It is not working on the ***for in do*** part of batch file: The system can not find the file specified. I have properly installed C:\cygwin\bin\grep[sed], and what is insteresting that this batch file is working on another machine. What am I missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Obviously you need more carets :-)  `...Process Name\]=\^^^&apos;\1\^^^&apos ...`

Answer (score 0):

Batch is very specific with what it accepts as valid syntax in `if` and `for` statements.  Change your `for` loop to the following style...

```
for /f "usebackq delims=|" %%f in (`dir /B /ON "%~1\SI0002\Workflow Process*"`) do (
  echo dir %%f
)
```

Specifically, put your `(` directly after the `do` directive and your `)` on a new line after the loop content lines.

I don't know if this will make your script work, but it should get you further.